# Check if user is a server member

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if certain user is a server member using their ID, but when I try to check it - my bot says user is not a server member even when he clearly is!
Here is what I tried:

```js
if(message.guild.members.cache.get('ID')) {
// ...code
}
```

What can I do to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member isn't cached. Always fetch a user and don't rely on the cache.

```js
const targetMember = await message.guild.members.fetch('ID');

if (targetMember) {
   // Member is in the guild
} else {
   // Member is not in the guild
}
```